# Can hibernate first level caching be disabled?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can hibernate first level caching be disabled?
Incase it can't be disabled, are there any work arounds?

Comment: There is no configuration to disable it. You need emulate the behaviour like removing entity (using `evict`) after selecting/updated, or use `clear` to clean the cache.

Comment: Why do you feel you need that? Are you using a different strategy than *session-per-request*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First level cache in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264039/first-level-cache-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate first level cache is associated with the Session object.
Hibernate first level cache is enabled by default and there is no way to disable it.
 However hibernate provides methods through which we can delete selected objects from the cache or clear the cache completely.
Any object cached in a session will not be visible to other sessions and when the session is closed, all the cached objects will also be lost.

Comment: `However hibernate provides methods through which we can delete selected objects from the cache or clear the cache completely.` - could u provide name/details of those methods.